# Trying to add class to body, based on taxonomy from a product/node

Tags: theming

Be kind to me, my forte is definitely NOT in the pre-process area... or hooks, etc. :-)

I'm using Omega 3.x in Drupal 7. I found a nice function that pulls the user's roles and prints each role as a class in the body. I'm trying to do the same by pulling taxonomy terms from a field "field_event_type" in a product I've got.

I already tried this:
[add css class to html element based on taxonomy?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69033/add-css-class-to-html-element-based-on-taxonomy)

... but it's not printing the class. I tried duplicating the logic from the "user role" part. Can anyone lend an assist? I'm trying to print the various taxonomy terms from the field "field_event_type". Much thanks in advance!!

```
function saleo_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $body_classes = array($vars['classes_array']);

  if ($vars['user']) {
    foreach($vars['user']->roles as $key => $role){
      $vars['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'role-' . drupal_html_class($role);
    }
  }

  if (!empty($vars['node'])) {
    $node = $vars['node'];
    if (!empty($node->field_event_type)) {  
      foreach($vars['node']->field_event_type as $key => $tags){
        $vars['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'tax-' . drupal_html_class($tags);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and make sure all elements you are working with exist for sure. You can do that by using `dpm()` function - e.g. `dpm($vars)` to see what exactly is there.